# how to show user details

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

hello now i have that code in my welcome.php when user login using login.php he is being redirected by redirect.php into welcome.php

```
<?php session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['userName']))
 {

    echo'<h1>WELCOME ' . $_SESSION['userName'] . '</h1>';
    echo'<h1>WELCOME ' . $_SESSION['R'] . '</h1>';
    echo'<br> <h1> <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a> </h1>';
 } 
 else
 {
    echo 'You are not logged In <br>';
    echo'<a href="index.php">LOGIN</a>';

 } ?>
```

i want to show R from my mysql database but i can't i searched many time but i couldn't find answer anyhelp?

Comment: `$_SESSION` variables aren't set until you set them. You need to query the database for `R` and declare it as the `$_SESSION['R']` value.

Comment: As _kittykittybangbang_ mentioned, you need to retrieve the data from the mysql-database before being able to assign it to the session variable `R`. Please post some code of the mysql-db implementation (obfuscate credentials) so we can see what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YgklAse.png here is a screenshot of the mysql database i tried to retrieve the date once but it didn't show up

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this when a member logs in. Query the database for that user then set the session variables

```
//Retrieve username and password from login feilds
$uname = clean($_POST['uname']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Query Database
$qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE userName='$uname' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);


//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();

        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] = $member['userName'];
       $_SESSION['SESS_USER_DATE'] = $member['R'];
        session_write_close();
        $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        //goto member homepage
        header("location: ../index.php");

    }else {
        //Login failed - try again
        header("location: ../login.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i got query failed if you could lead me to a good php login script cause i think my one is pretty bad

Comment: [Here](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/PHP-Simple-login-script/9963) is a simple guide to get you started.